# Metodo para filtrar cifras Java

Tags: java

estoy intentando crear un método con Java que filtre cifras de la siguiente manera:
El método pide dos int (int n, int x). Si n es, por ejemplo, 4232 y x es 2, n se filtrará haciendo que todos los 2 de n se cambien por ceros, es decir;
filtraCifrasX(4232, 2) devuelve el entero 4030.
He probado unas cuantas cosas pero no lo consigo.
Gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

```
public static int filtraCifrasX(int n, int x) {
     if (n < 10) {if (n==x) {return 0;} else {return n;}}
    else {
        if (n%10 == x) {n = n-n%10;filtraCifrasX(n/10,x);return n;}
        else {return filtraCifrasX(n/10,x);}
    }
}
```

Este es el metodo tal y como lo tengo ahora mismo, el problema que tengo es que si introduzco 4232 como había puesto de ejemplo, me devuelve 4230; pero no 4030 que es lo que debería ocurrir.

Comment: Se me olvidó mencionar que lo estoy intentando resolver mediante recursión. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Primero conviertes el numero de "n" a un String

```
int n = 4232
String cifra = String.valueOf(n)
```

despues remplazas los numeros "2" por "0" de la siguiente manera

```
cifra.replaceAll("2","0");
```

y listo al final tienes que establecer de nuevo esa cifra como un entero

```
n = Integer.parseInt(n);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias :) Voy a probar ahora mismo a ver si lo consigo.

Answer (score 0):

Ya he conseguido que el metodo funcione exactamente como yo quería, lo dejo aquí por si a alguien le hace falta en algún momento.

```
/** Devuelve un entero con las mismas cifras que n, excepto que las
 * apariciones del digito x aparecen cambiadas por 0.
 * Precondicion: n >= 0, 1 <= x <= 9.
 */
public static int filtraCifrasX(int n, int x) {
    if (n < 10) {if (n==x) {return 0;} else {return n;}}
    else {
        if (n%10 == x) {return filtraCifrasX(n/10,x)*10;}
        else {return filtraCifrasX(n/10,x)*10 + n%10;}
    }
}
```